# How to use C++ standard smart pointers with Windows HANDLEs?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11

I was wondering if there is a way to use `unique_ptr<T>` with Windows HANDLEs?

I was thinking to replace the `std::default_delete` with specific `handle_trats` that calls `CloseHandle`. The problem is that `HANDLE` is defined as `void*` `unique_ptr<void>` won't compile as `sizeof(void)` is not defined.

So far I see only two possibilities:

1. Create a wrapper class for HANDLEs and use it like this: `unique_ptr<new CHandle(h)>`. This pretty much makes the `unique_ptr<T>` itself useless.
2. Use `HANDLE` specific smart pointer class that resembles `unique_ptr<T>`.

What do you think is better choice? What would you suggest?

The question can be extended for `COM IUnknown` pointers - can `CComPtr` be replaced by any of the standard smart pointers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The question can be extended for COM IUnknown pointers - can CComPtr
>   be replaced by any of the standard smart pointers?

Yes. You don't specialize `std::default_deleter`, you simply replace the deleter type.

```
struct COMDeleter {
    template<typename T> void operator()(T* ptr) {
        ptr->Release();
    }
};
unique_ptr<IUnknown, COMDeleter> ptr; // Works fine
```

The same principle applies to `shared_ptr` and indeed, to `HANDLE`.

Answer (score 6):

Create a specific smart pointer class, won't take long. Don't abuse library classes. Handle semantics is quite different from that of a C++ pointer; for one thing, dereferencing a HANDLE makes no sense.

One more reason to use a custom smart handle class - NULL does not always mean an empty handle. Sometimes it's INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, which is not the same (actually -1).

Comment: I wrote my own set up HANDLE-specific classes, as some handles require `CloseHandle()` while others require different API-specific funtions, some HANDLEs are set to INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE when not assigned and others are set to NULL instead, etc.  I wrote a set of base classes for the bulk of the work, and then use custom trait classes to handle closure and assignment issues.

Comment: -1 for re-implementing library classes badly. They are explicitly designed for this functionality, it's not an abuse. You will introduce pointless new bugs and code.

Comment: +1 for recognizing that pointers and HANDLEs are different things with different semantics.  Shoehorning HANDLEs into a smart pointer type gives you a bunch of methods that don't really make sense for HANDLEs.

Answer (score 4):

inspired by Alexander Drichel's solution, here is even shorter

```
std::unique_ptr< HANDLE, decltype(&CloseHandle) > uniqueHandle( nullptr, CloseHandle );
```

Works in MSVC 2010. Note that you need to specify '&' for the function name in decltype() to deduce a pointer-to-function type.

Answer (score 3):

You can typedef your `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter

```
struct handle_deleter
{
    void operator()(void* handle)
    {
        if(handle != nullptr)
            CloseHandle(handle);
    }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<void, handle_deleter> UniqueHandle_t;
UniqueHandle_t ptr(CreateFile(...));
```

Answer (score 3):

yet another solution

```
std::unique_ptr< void, void(*)( HANDLE ) > uniqueHandle( file, []( HANDLE h ) { ::CloseHandle( h ); } );
```

Answer (score 2):

A HANDLE does not always close with CloseHandle(), beware.
For example a HANDLE opened with FindNextFile() must be closed by FindClose().

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Deleter class that will release the handle instead of calling delete().

You can see in this **[LINK](http://nealabq.com/blog/2008/12/02/array_deleter/)** how they've solved deleting arrays with a shared_ptr (unique_ptr also has a constructor that recieves a Delete class)

```
  struct handle_deleter
  {   
    void operator ()( HANDLE handle)
      { CloseHandle(p); }
  };

  HANDLE blah = GetSomeHandle();
  unique_ptr myPointer(blah,handle_deleter);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using smart pointers with handles.

I recommend you to take a look at [*A Proposal to Add additional RAII Wrappers to the Standard Library*](http://www.andrewlsandoval.com/scope_exit/) and at [*the drawbacks of using smart pointers with handles*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14878121).

Personally, I'm making use of the reference implementation of that proposal instead of using `std::unique_ptr` for these situations.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `CloseHandle()` to "close" a handle instead using `delete`. They will be deleted by Windows as soon as they are not opened elsewhere. So you could write a wrapper that calls CloseHandle() instead of deleteing it. You could also write your own smartpointer class which might be better as there is no need of a wrapper anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a handy little "custom_ptr" I use for dealing with a `HANDLE`.
`C++17` is required in order for this to compile. This idea was lifted from another SO post, I only added the `std::remove_pointer_t<T>` so that I wouldn't have to pass `void` as the `custom_ptr` type parameter.

**Definition**

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

template<auto fn>
using deleter_from_fn = std::integral_constant<decltype( fn ), fn>;

template<typename T, auto fn>
using custom_ptr = std::unique_ptr<typename std::remove_pointer_t<T>, deleter_from_fn<fn>>;
```

**Use**

```
custom_ptr<HANDLE, &CloseHandle> phandle{
    CreateFileMapping( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nullptr, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 1024, L"FileName" ) };
```